# Java Execution Service

Tags: java

Sometimes I am getting current exception:

```
[java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.ExecutorCompletionService$QueueingFuture@746c196 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@5eeac923[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 0]]
```

I am calling `runAndAwaitResult()` function limiting it to 100ms. If results successfully received and ready I am shutting down a ExecuorService if timeout has been exceeded I am taking available results and shutting down service as well. But sometimes I am getting that exception. How should I handle it or what is the best way terminating service to avoid such exception. Note I cannot wait for gentle shutdown I have just 100 ms for both jobs.

```
try{
        generalPersonalisationHandler = new GeneralPersonalisationHandler(resourceStack);
        com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult result = timeLimiter.callWithTimeout(new Callable<com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult>() {
            @Override
            public com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult call() throws Exception {
                com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult result = generalPersonalisationHandler.runAndAwaitResults(customerCookie);
                generalPersonalisationHandler.shutdown();
                return result;
            }
        }, timeout, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, true);

        PersonalisationData response = transformAvailableResults(result);
        return  response;
    }
    catch (UncheckedTimeoutException e) {
        String errorMsg = String.format("TIMEOUT for RunGeneralPersonalisation() execution time has exceeded maximum limit of: [%s] ms", timeout);
        ErrorLogger.error(errorMsg, e);
        com.company.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult result = generalPersonalisationHandler.returnAvailableResults();
        generalPersonalisationHandler.shutdown();
        return transformAvailableResults(result);
    }
```

GeneralPersonalisationHandler.java

```
public class GeneralPersonalisationHandler {

    private GeneralPersonalisationResult generalPersonalisationResult;

    private final int SUBMITTED_JOBS = 2;
    private CompletionService<JobResult> completionService;
    private ResourceStack resourceStack;
    private ExecutorService executor;
    public GeneralPersonalisationHandler(ResourceStack resourceStack){
        this.executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(SUBMITTED_JOBS);
        this.completionService = new ExecutorCompletionService<JobResult>(executor);
        this.resourceStack = resourceStack;
    }

    public GeneralPersonalisationResult runAndAwaitResults(String customerCookie) throws Exception {



            Job customerEventsJob = new CustomerEventsJob(customerCookie, resourceStack);
            Job customerInfoJob = new CustomerPersonalInfoJob(customerCookie, resourceStack);

            completionService.submit(customerInfoJob);
            completionService.submit(customerEventsJob);


            generalPersonalisationResult = new GeneralPersonalisationResult();
            for (int handledJobs = 0; handledJobs < SUBMITTED_JOBS; handledJobs++) {
                Future<JobResult> result = completionService.take();

                JobResult jobResult = result.get();
                if (jobResult instanceof CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult) {
                    CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult customerPersonalInfoJobResult = (CustomerPersonalInfoJobResult) jobResult;
                    generalPersonalisationResult.setCustomerPersonalInfoJobResult(customerPersonalInfoJobResult);
                }

                if (jobResult instanceof CustomerEventsJobResult) {
                    CustomerEventsJobResult customerEventsJobResult = (CustomerEventsJobResult) jobResult;
                    generalPersonalisationResult.setCustomerEventsJobResult(customerEventsJobResult);
                }
            }

        }

        return generalPersonalisationResult;
    }

    public GeneralPersonalisationResult returnAvailableResults(){
        return this.generalPersonalisationResult;
    }

    public void shutdown(){
        if(!this.executor.isShutdown()) {
            this.executor.shutdown();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
catch (UncheckedTimeoutException e) {
    String errorMsg = String.format("TIMEOUT for RunGeneralPersonalisation() execution time has exceeded maximum limit of: [%s] ms", timeout);
    ErrorLogger.error(errorMsg, e);
    com.thehutgroup.personalisation.jobs.result.GeneralPersonalisationResult result = generalPersonalisationHandler.returnAvailableResults();
    generalPersonalisationHandler.shutdown();  // possible problem !!!
    return transformAvailableResults(result);
}
```

Looks like if UncheckedTimeoutException occurs you shutting down executor service, and after that if you try to add some task, you will have RejectedExecutionException.

Call shutdown only when you sure that any task won't be added.

Comment: probably you are right, I will wrap creation of `GeneralPersonalisationHandler` instance into another class so that other threads would not be able to access same executor. Do you think its sounds reasonable and will help?

Comment: I don't have full vision on your project, but i'd advise to use one executor and care about shutdown. Anyway you can try your approach but keep in mind, fixed pool executors keep all threads till shutdown.